Fourier transform of $f(x)=x\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}$, for $a<b$ reals.
As stated, this problem is pretty straigth forward. Using the normal definition of the Fourier transform I get, $$\widehat{x\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}=\int_{a}^{b}xe^{-2\pi i x \xi}dx=\frac{e^{-2\pi i a \xi}(-1-2i\pi a\xi)+e^{-2\pi i b \xi}(1+2\pi i b \xi)}{4\pi^2\xi^2}$$ But by using Fourier properties I get a different result. Using the fact that $$\widehat{(2\pi ix)^{|n|}T}=\partial^{n}\widehat{T}$$ we see that, $$\widehat{\frac{2\pi ix\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}{2\pi i}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}'$$ Now, computing $$\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}=\int_{a}^{b}e^{-2\pi i x \xi}dx=-\frac{i(e^{-2\pi i a \xi}-e^{-2\pi i b \xi})}{2\pi\xi}$$ deriving with respect to $\xi$ and dividing by $2\pi i$ we get the same result, so I guess this is the result? Nontheless, there should be some principal value functions in there as well as some delta functions but I don't have any idea on how to do so. For example, my professor has shown that $$\widehat{x\mathcal{X}_{(0,\infty)}}(\xi)=\frac{\delta_0}{2}-\partial\Big(\text{p.v}\frac{1}{\xi}\Big)$$

Why should there be ? $b$ finite is different from $b$ infinite ...

What you did in both instances is completely fine. The Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is again a (uniformly continuous) function, and so it already wasn't feasible to find another expression for $\widehat{x\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}$ which features non-cancelling terms with Dirac deltas, principal values, etc... since they are not distributions tied to functions (non-cancelling in the sense that they would be equal up to a function).

I more a less understand what you mean. For intance, my function $f(x)$ belongs to the class of functions $L^1$, since it is a bounded function on an interval, and thus it converges absolutely. So, I can use the normal definition for the Fourier transform. Mainly, $\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi i x \xi}dx$. Which ends up giving the expression above, right? Anyways, I have found another way of finding this Fourier transform and I wanted to check if I have done everything correctly. I will post the result in the following comment.

@HornyPigeon54 That is another correct way to look at it yes. (Note that it should be $\chi_{[a,\infty)} - \chi_{(b, \infty)}$, you swapped $a$ and $b$ by mistake)

Well, I might aswell post as an answer. As I was saying, using the following results, $$\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[0,\infty)}}(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}\delta+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\text{p.v}\frac{1}{\xi}$$ $$\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}(x)=\mathcal{X}_{[b,\infty)}-\mathcal{X}_{[a,\infty)}=\mathcal{X}_{[0,\infty)}(x-b)-\mathcal{X}_{[0,\infty)}(x-a)$$ We get the following, $$\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}(\xi)=\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[0,\infty)}(x-b)}-\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[0,\infty)}(x-a)}=e^{-2\pi ib\xi}\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[0,\infty)}}(\xi)-e^{-2\pi ia\xi}\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[0,\infty)}}(\xi)=(e^{-2\pi ib\xi}-e^{-2\pi ia\xi})\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[0,\infty)}}(\xi)$$
Finally, computing the derivative of the above expression and joining it to the following result we get what we are looking for $$\widehat{x\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}'$$ where $$\widehat{\mathcal{X}_{[a,b]}}'(\xi)=\Big((e^{-2\pi ib\xi}-e^{-2\pi ia\xi})(\frac{1}{2}\delta_0+\frac{1}{2\pi 
i}\text{p.v}\frac{1}{\xi})\Big)'$$

I mean, this time I get the delta's and principal values because I am working with $a$'s and $b$'s which can be infinite right?
